# Passing optional arguments from optparse

Tags: python, python-2.6, optparse, optional-arguments

I'm trying to figure out how to pass optional arguments from optparse. The problem I'm having is if an optparse option is not specified, it defaults to a None type, but if I pass the None type into a function, it yells at me instead of using the default (Which is understandable and valid).

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database=options.db, hostname=options.hostname, port=options.port)
```

The question is, how do I use the function's defaults for optional arguments but still pass in user inputs if there is an input without having a huge number of if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function `remove_none_values` that filters a dictionary for none-valued arguments.

```
def remove_none_values(d):
    return dict((k,v) for (k,v) in d.iteritems() if not v is None)

kwargs = {
  'database': options.db,
  'hostname': options.hostname,
  ...
}
conn = psycopg2.connect(**remove_none_values(kwargs))
```

Or, define a function wrapper that removes none values before passing the data on to the original function.

```
def ignore_none_valued_kwargs(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        newkwargs = dict((k,v) for (k,v) in d.iteritems() if not v is None)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

my_connect = ignore_none_valued_kwargs(psycopg2)
conn = my_connect(database=options.db, hostname=options.hostname, port=options.port)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I wish there was a less hacked together way than making a dict and removing the None types.

Answer (score 0):

The `opo` module of my `thebops` package (`pip install thebops`, https://bitbucket.org/therp/thebops) contains an `add_optval_option` function.
This uses an additional keyword argument `empty` which specifies the value to use if the option is used without a value.  If one of the option strings is found in the commandline, this value is injected into the argument list.

This is still hackish, but at least it is made a simple-to-use function ...

It works well under the following circumstances:

- The argument vector does already exist when the option is created.  This is usually true.
- All programs I found which sport arguments with optional values require the *given* value to be attached as `--option=value` or `-ovalue` rather than `--option value` or `-o value`.

Maybe I'll tweak `thebops.optparse` to support the `empty` argument as well; but I'd like to have a test suite first to prevent regressions, preferably the original `Optik` / `optparse` tests.

This is the code:

```
from sys import argv
def add_optval_option(pog, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Add an option which can be specified without a value;
    in this case, the value (if given) must be contained
    in the same argument as seen by the shell,
    i.e.:

    --option=VALUE, --option will work;
    --option VALUE will *not* work

    Arguments:
    pog -- parser or group
    empty -- the value to use when used without a value

    Note:
      If you specify a short option string as well, the syntax given by the
      help will be wrong; -oVALUE will be supported, -o VALUE will not!
      Thus it might be wise to create a separate option for the short
      option strings (in a "hidden" group which isn't added to the parser after
      being populated) and just mention it in the help string.
    """
    if 'empty' in kwargs:
        empty_val = kwargs.pop('empty')
        # in this case it's a good idea to have a <default> value; this can be
        # given by another option with the same <dest>, though
        for i in range(1, len(argv)):
            a = argv[i]
            if a == '--':
                break
            if a in args:
                argv.insert(i+1, empty_val)
                break
    pog.add_option(*args, **kwargs)
```